# Flattening Device & Meter data using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using a tree-control that requires I flatten the data before handing it to the control.  I've tried various online examples and cannot quite 'flatten' the data correctly.

- Devices have many Meters
- The resulting list must be a (flattened) list of DeviceHierarchyDataItem

**CODE LOOKS LIKE:**
I am guessing I've taken the wrong road here...

```
public IQueryable<DeviceHierarchyDataItem> Query(int circuitConnectId)
{
    var devices = (from device in UnitOfWork.Device
                   join deviceCircuit in UnitOfWork.DeviceCircuit on device.Id equals deviceCircuit.DeviceId
                   where
                        deviceCircuit.CircuitConnectId == circuitConnectId
                   select device)
                   .Include( x=> x.Meters);

    // Not sure what to do NEXT (previous attempts have failed)
}
```

**CLASSES:**

```
public class DeviceHierarchyDataItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //<-- the 'Id' of the Device or Meter

    public int? ChildOf { get; set; }  //<-- the 'Id' of the PARENT Device or NULL

    public int CircuitConnectId { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; } //<-- the 'Name' of the Device or Meter
}

public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public List<Meter> Meters { get; set; }
}

public class Meter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string MeterName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) to flatten a collection of collections.

```
var devices = (from device in UnitOfWork.Device
               join deviceCircuit in UnitOfWork.DeviceCircuit on device.Id equals deviceCircuit.DeviceId
               where
                    deviceCircuit.CircuitConnectId == circuitConnectId
               select device)
               .Include( x=> x.Meters);

var deviceHierarchyDataItems = devices
    .SelectMany(device => device.Meters.Select(meter => new DeviceHierarchyDataItem
    {
        Id = meter.Id,
        ChildOf = device.Id,
        CircuitConnectId = 0, // don't know what you need here
        DisplayName = meter.MeterName
    }))
    .Concat(devices.Select(device => new DeviceHierarchyDataItem
    {
        Id = device.Id,
        ChildOf = null,
        CircuitConnectId = 0, // don't know what you need here
        DisplayName = device.DeviceName
    }));
```

Or alternatively:

```
var deviceHierarchyDataItems = devices
    .SelectMany(device => device.Meters.Select(meter => new DeviceHierarchyDataItem
    {
        Id = meter.Id,
        ChildOf = device.Id,
        CircuitConnectId = 0, // don't know what you need here
        DisplayName = meter.MeterName
    }).Concat(new List<DeviceHierarchyDataItem>()
    {
        new DeviceHierarchyDataItem
        {
            Id = device.Id,
            ChildOf = null,
            CircuitConnectId = 0, // don't know what you need here
            DisplayName = device.DeviceName
        }
    }));
```

Comment: This makes total sense...I just needed to see a good one...thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic Data](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData) is a wonderful package for handling lists.

Use the reactive tree feature to flatten the list. Example found [here](https://dynamic-data.org/2015/07/07/reactive-tree-using-dynamic-data/).

Answer (score 1):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication86
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int circuitConnectId = 123;
            var devices = (from device in UnitOfWork.Device
                           join deviceCircuit in UnitOfWork.DeviceCircuit on device.Id equals deviceCircuit.Id
                           where
                                deviceCircuit.CircuitConnectId == circuitConnectId
                           select new { device = device, deviceCircuit = deviceCircuit })
                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               meters = x.device.Meters.Select(y => new { deviceName = x.device.DeviceName, deviceId = x.device.Id, meterId = y.Id, meterName = y.MeterName, circuitId = x.deviceCircuit.Id, circuitDisplayName = x.deviceCircuit.DisplayName }),
                           }).ToList();


         }
    }
    public class UnitOfWork
    {
        public static List<Device> Device { get; set; }
        public static List<DeviceHierarchyDataItem> DeviceCircuit { get; set; }
    }
    public class DeviceHierarchyDataItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } //<-- the 'Id' of the Device or Meter

        public int? ChildOf { get; set; }  //<-- the 'Id' of the PARENT Device or NULL

        public int CircuitConnectId { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; } //<-- the 'Name' of the Device or Meter
    }

    public class Device
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string DeviceName { get; set; }

        public List<Meter> Meters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meter
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string MeterName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong for 2 reasons: 1) It materializes the output while the original function returned IQueryable. 2) The result is not flattened, it's a collection of IEnumerable.

Comment: It is flat.  All the properties of the classes are part of the same enumerable item.  If you have properties in Class A child class B and Grand-Child class C, I made all the properties in the same anonymous object.